# How to show image field in frontend phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, database, plugin

**i have done this: 
but it is not showing banner image:** 
**step1.**

```
/app/code/local/Company/ModName/Block/Adminhtml/ModName/Edit/Tab/Form.php

$fieldset->addField('banner_image', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('pictos')->__('Banner Image'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'banner_image',
));
```

**step2.**

```
if(isset($_FILES['banner_image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['banner_image']['tmp_name']))) {
  try {
    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('banner_image');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); 
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .blog. DS ;

    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['banner_image']['name']);

    $data['banner_image'] = $_FILES['banner_image']['name'];
  }catch(Exception $e) {

  }
} 
else {      

    if(isset($data['banner_image']['delete']) && $data['banner_image']['delete'] == 1)
        $data['image_main'] = '';
    else
        unset($data['banner_image']);
}
```

**step three:**

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('blog/post'),
    'banner_image',
    'VARCHAR(255) NULL'
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

**in frontend i call banner image like this:**

```
if($this->getpost()->getBannerImage()){?>
        <div class="banner_area">
<?php $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'/blog/'.$this->getpost()->getBannerImage();?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getpost()->getBannerImage();?>">
        </div>
```

but no result

Answer (score 1):

I can see one thing straight off you have your path set wrong in your controller.

```
 $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .blog. DS ;
```

should be

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'blog'. DS ;
```

Comment: Hi, eirik sorry ..  $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'blog'. DS ; i have done this too ... but there is no result ... is there any issue with file permission with magento skin folder i don't see any folder with name blog in my skin images directory... but in media folder there is a folder for blog with but there is no image which i save from admin of my module ....

Comment: Inside the database table for the blog post. What is it saving the image name as? Also ensure the images don't have spaces/special characters in their names.